# Mantle convert 0 and 1 to BOOL automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, github-mantle

Does Mantle already converts int values 0 and 1 in JSON to objective-C BOOL values?

I have a model:

```
@interface MyModel : MTLModel

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isValid;

@end
```

And lets say JSON is:

```
{ is_valid: 0 } OR { is_valid: 1 }
```

I want to know if Mantle would automatically convert `is_valid` into Objective-C BOOL value to do I have to explicity mention the following:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer)isValidJSONTransfermer {
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_valueMappingTransformerWithDictionary:@{@(0) : @(NO),
                                                                           @(1) : @(YES)}];
}
```

Comment: Doubtful, given JSON has a boolean data type.

Comment: Does it automatically converts `boolean` into BOOL? I can most probably get API changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is handled for you; you don't need to use the mapping transformer.

Mantle internally calls [`setValue:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValue%3aforKey%3a) to set the value. The 0 or 1 will be an `NSNumber`, and `setValue:forKey:` will use the `boolValue` on `NSNumber` to get a value, as your property is declared as a `BOOL`.

This behaviour of Key-Value Coding is described under [Scalar and Structure Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-BAJEAIEE).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert a string to boolean use this transformer:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)sectionJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_valueMappingTransformerWithDictionary:@{@"0" : @(NO),
                                                                           @"1" : @(YES)}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)awesomeJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer valueTransformerForName: MTLBooleanValueTransformerName];
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue