# how to process BOOL in Mantle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, model, github-mantle

I have MyModel inheriting from MTLModel (using the GitHub Mantle pod). **MyModel.h**

```
@interface MyModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL *nsfw;

@end
```

in **MyModel.m**, I have tried

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)nsfwJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer valueTransformerForName:MTLBooleanValueTransformerName];
}
```

and

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)nsfwJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_valueMappingTransformerWithDictionary:@{
                                                                           @"0": @(NO),
                                                                           @"1": @(YES)
                                                                               }];
}
```

**both not working**

and using Charles get the field in Response JSON data, 
[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfceV.png) as shown .

meanwhile, in the **dictionary** **serialized**, 
 **the relevant fields** is

**`nsfw = 0`**

futher, the results of breakpoint debug in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVqtP.png)

It's not my expect, I think it should be `nsfw = false` something like that

I feel something is wrong..

**So does this mean that Boolean becomes NSNumber by serialization?**

**What should I do to solve the problem?**

**any tips or suggestion is appreciate~**

Comment: Related Issues :
https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/issues/466                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670702/mantle-convert-0-and-1-to-bool-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know by [looking at this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670702/mantle-convert-0-and-1-to-bool-automatically), Mantle already converts int values 0 and 1 in JSON to Objective-C BOOL values.

I think your problem comes down to a simple typo.

Instead of:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL *nsfw;
```

which is a pointer.

Do:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL nsfw;
```

which is the C type that Mantle knows to translate into.